# Hotkey to close a code block with curly brackets in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Suppose I have a line of `Java` code in `Eclipse`:

```
System.out.println(1);
```

However I decide that I only want to print `1` if some condition is true, so I type:

```
if(Math.random()<0.5) { //As an example
    System.out.println(1);
}
```

Once I have typed `if(Math.random()<0.5)`, is there any way to automatically insert `{` and `}`? (Perhaps I may have to pre-indent the `System.out.println(1)` in order to tell the algorithm where to place `}`).

Comment: I don't think so..perhaps eclipse wants you to do some work too!! :P

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be select the `System.out.println(1);` statement and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> then choose `surround with if` option.

Then type in the condition in the small text box appeared. After typing the condition press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Refer image below
[image]

Comment: Does it answers your question?If so accept it else edit your post with more details